# Use javascript to return true if a string contains an exact match

Tags: javascript, string-matching, indexof

I've been using the `.indexOf('') > -1` in order to check whether there's a match in a string. The problem that I'm having is that when I'm performing the match on multiple strings, I get a match on the string for both EIFT and EI (since EIFT contains EI), and so the function returns `true` for both sentences. What I need is a way for this to only return true for `function eIft` if the string is "EIFT", but not for `EI`.

My current code is as follows, and I've been trying to think of ways around this but haven't had any success yet.

```
function eI(mystring){
    return mystring.indexOf("EI") > -1
}

function eIft(mystring){
    return mystring.indexOf("EIFT") > -1
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what is wrong with the function `eIft`? It will return false if `myString` contains `EI` but not `EIFT`.

Comment: I don't understand. If it contains `EIFT` then it also contains `EI`, so why shouldn't it match? Are you saying that you want to *prefer* the longer over the shorter? If so, then search for the longer first.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't respond to requests for clarification?

Comment: @cookiemonster @cybersam, the functions work, but the problem lies in that the `function eI` will return true for string `"blah blah eift"`, when I only want `function eIft` to return true for `"blah blah eift"`. Hope that clears up your questions :)

Comment: @maudulus: No, not really. It's an unreasonable expectation for the `eI` function to not return `true` when it's designed to return `true`. And it's even less clear now that the answer you accepted below would return `false` for both functions. Your problem's description is vague. [What is the XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `===`; that will do an exact match of strings. Use `indexOf` only if you're checking whether the string *contains* another string.

```
function eI (mystring) {
    return mystring === "EI";
}

function eIFt(mystring) {
    return mystring === "EIFT";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking inside a string for you values (e.g. heleilo), then you need to confirm your positive results for the 'EI' check:

```
function eI(mystrng) {
    return mystring.indexOf("EI") != -1 && !eIFt(mystring);
}
```

This would only work provided they don't both exist in different occurences (e.g. heleileifto). In this case, you have to check the immediate following characters:

```
function eI(mystring) {
    var pos = mystring.indexOf("EI");

    if (pos != -1) { // found
        var char1 = mystring[pos + 2];
        var char2 = mystring[pos + 3];

        return char1 !== 'F' && char2 !== 'T';
    }
}
```

OR

```
function eI(mystring) {
    var pos = mystring.indexOf("EI");

    if (pos != -1) { // found
        return pos != eIFt(mystring); // they won't have the same index
    }
}
```